# How is the Lemma Used in this Proof of Zorn's Lemma

Tags: proof-explanation, set-theory

Two statements are made in [Grayson's paper](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/%7Ezink/Zorn.pdf). First, a lemma:

> **Lemma 2.1.** *Suppose $X$ is a partially ordered set, and $F$ is a collection of subsets which are well ordered by the ordering of $X$. Suppose also that for any $C, D ∈ F$, either $C ≤ D$ or $D ≤ C$. Let $E = \bigcup_{C∈F} C$. Then $E$ is well ordered, and for each $C ∈ F$ we have $C ≤ E$.*

and then, the main result:

> **Theorem 2.2** (Zorn's Lemma). *A partially ordered set $X$ with upper bounds for its well ordered subsets has a maximal element*.

He never explicitly uses Lemma 2.1 in the proof of the Theorem 2.2, and I'm left wondering *where* in the proof of the latter is the former used. Here is the proof of Theorem 2.2:

> *Proof:* Suppose not. For each well ordered subset $C ⊆ X$ pick an upper bound $g(C) \notin C$. A well ordered subset $C ⊆ X$ such that $c = g(\{c' ∈ C | c' < c\})$ for every $c ∈ C$ will be called a $g$-set.
> We claim that if $C$ and $D$ are $g$-sets, then either $C ≤ D$ or $D ≤ C$. To see this, let $W$ be the union of the subsets $B ⊆ X$ satisfying $B ≤ C$ and $B ≤ D$.
> Since a union of closed subsets is closed, we see that $W ≤ C$ and $W ≤ D$, and $W$ is the largest subset of $X$ with this property. If $W = C$ or $W = D$ we are
> done, so assume $W < C$ and $W < D$, and pick elements $c ∈ C$ and $d ∈ D$ so that $W = \{c' ∈ C | c' < c\} = \{d' ∈ D | d' < d\}$. Since $C$ and $D$ are $g$-sets, we see that $c = g(W) = d$. Let $W' = W ∪ \{g(W)\}$; it’s a $g$-set larger than $W$ with $W' ≤ C$ and $W' ≤ D$, contradicting the maximality of $W$. Now let $W$ be the union of all the $g$-sets. It’s a $g$-set, too, and it’s the largest $g$-set, but $W' = W ∪ {g(W)}$ is a larger $g$-set, yielding a contradiction.

***Where is Lemma 2.1 used?***

Comment: What is a g-set?

Comment: How do you know that he uses the lemma in the proof of the theorem?

Comment: @Filippo I don't, but why would he include it if not?

Answer (score 1):

The lemma is used when the author writes "It's a $g$-set, too, and it's the largest $g$-set". The "it" here is $W$, the union of the family of all $g$-sets.

To verify the claim, we must check (1) $W$ is well-ordered, (2) $W\subseteq X$, (3) for all $w\in W$, $w = g(\{w'\in W\mid w'<w\})$, and (4) for every $g$-set $C\leq X$, $C\leq W$.

(1) and (4) follow directly from the Lemma, (2) is obvious, and (3) is an easy check.